# Push from one repo to another in same org, using GitHub Actions and no explicitly generated token?

Tags: github-actions

I have two repos in my organisation: `www` (TypeScript, SCSS, etc.), and `myorg-github-io` (HTML, CSS).

My workflow in `www` has:

```yaml
env:
    GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.CUSTOM_GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

which it uses to push to `master` branch of `myorg-github-io`. The `CUSTOM_GITHUB_TOKEN` is in my `www` repository secrets. I manually generated it, and it has the ability to push to anything my user account can push to.

Rather than this approach, is there a [*principle of least privilege*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege) solution, perhaps utilising some automatic token passing method (where I don't need to manually generate the token)?

Comment: Rather than giving it full access, use a [fine-grained token](https://github.blog/2022-10-18-introducing-fine-grained-personal-access-tokens-for-github/)? Alternatively it might be simpler to push between different branches _in one repo_, so there's no cross-traffic.

Comment: Yes I can manually generate a fine-grained token; but I'm trying to see if there's an automated way. And yes with GitHub Pages I can just use another branch; but I prefer it this way (2 repos).